# jQuery: $(this).next().focus(); won't work if the <input> tags are followed by <td> or <br> tags

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to limit the number of digits entered into an `<input>` field and then jump to the next field. The following is the code:

HTML:

```
<input class=time ...><input class=time...><input class=time ...>
```

JS:

```
$('.time').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var data = $(this).val();
  data = data.replace(/\D/g,''); // Delete all non-digits
  len = data.length;    
  if (len==3) {
    data = data.slice(0,2) + ':' + data[2];  // Add a ':'
  } else if (len>=4) {
    data = data.slice(0,2) + ':' + data.slice(2,4);
    $(this).next('.time').focus();  
  }
  $(this).val(data);
});
```

The above will work. But if I add the input fields into a table the `$(this).next('.time').focus();` statement will not work:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class=time ...></td>
  <td><input class=time ...></td>
  <td><input class=time ...></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I also found that if the `<input>` tags are followed by `<br>`, the `focus()` statement will also fail:

```
<input class=time ...><br>
<input class=time ...><br>
<input class=time ...><br>
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

well that is because inputs are no longer having sibling relationship, their parent tds do. You need to traverse to parent td and then find input in next td element:

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.time').focus();
```

Comment: Should probably add the why of the matter here... But overall this is right.

Comment: yo dawg i heard you like chaining

Comment: Chaining is the way to go!! :D